# Using jQuery to change header text color while over certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the text color on a fixed header when certain div elements are under it. This is the code that I have.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.white-header').each(function() {
        scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
        elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        elementBottom = $(this).outerHeight() + elementTop;
        if (scrollPosition > elementTop && scrollPosition < elementBottom) {
            $('#header').css('color','#fff');
        }
        if (scrollPosition < elementTop || scrollPosition > elementBottom) {
            $('#header').css('color','#222');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it only seems for work for one element. If there is only one div with class .white-header everything works great. But when there are mutiple only one of them works (seems to be the last one that works).

Here is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/augpergo/3/) showing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While looping over `.white-header` elements, when the first element matches the conditions, text color is changed to white. However, the second element doesn't match the conditions, so text color is immediately changed back to black. Instead of checking if all elements matches the condition, you should check if any of them does.

Try this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (Array.prototype.some.call($('.white-header'), function(element) {
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
    elementBottom = $(element).outerHeight() + elementTop;
    if (scrollPosition > elementTop && scrollPosition < elementBottom) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  })) {
    $('#header').css('color', '#fff');
  } else {
    $('#header').css('color', '#222');
  }
});
```

See [updated JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/augpergo/4/).

You can also break the loop after finding matching element using `return false`, like that:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.white-header').each(function() {
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    elementBottom = $(this).outerHeight() + elementTop;
    if (scrollPosition > elementTop && scrollPosition < elementBottom) {
      $('#header').css('color', '#fff');
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $('#header').css('color', '#222');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a two `.white-header` elements. while looping over `.white-header` elements, when scroll position doesn't match with condition, text color will be `#222`. So you need to check for prevent duplicate `css` method calls.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var _isOnWhiteHeader = false;
  $('.white-header').each(function() {
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    elementBottom = $(this).outerHeight() + elementTop;

    if (scrollPosition > elementTop && scrollPosition < elementBottom) {
      $('#header').css('color', '#fff');
      _isOnWhiteHeader = true;
    }
    else if(!_isOnWhiteHeader){
      $('#header').css('color', '#222');
    }
  });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/augpergo/5/)**